# AJAX query not always updating information consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am experiecing some issues with AJAX updating the page. The actual data in the database is updated but this is not always reflecting in real time on the web page.

For example, I have the following event:

```
    $("#add_note").click(function(e) { 
        //e.preventDefault();       
        $("#add_note_form").validate({ 
            rules: {
              contact_note: {
                required: true
              }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                contact.modal_update({
                    'obj' : $('#add_note_form'),
                    'uri' : '/contact/add_note/'
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
```

This function when a new note is created calls a callback to validate the form fields first and then if successful calls a callback inside a seperate class to conduct the update. See the modal_update class below:

```
// Update modal
this.modal_update = function(data) 
{//
    // Declare a few variables for the data object we've received
    obj = data.obj // The form element to serialize
    uri = data.uri;
    // Get the form ID from the data-target attribute 
    id = obj.attr('data-target');
    // URL to send to 
    url = this.site_url + uri + id;     
    // The form object
    this.post_data(obj.serialize(),url);
    // Hide Modal
    obj.closest('.modal').modal('hide');    
    // Refresh 
    this.refresh();
}
```

This then figures out the correct route to ajax and calls a ajax call back inside the same class:

```
// AJAX post
this.post_data = function(obj,uri)
{
    $.ajax({
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        url: uri,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
           if (response.success == true)
           {

                $("#alert_success .msg").html(response.message);
                $("#alert_success").fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
           }
            else 
           {
                $("#alert_error .msg").html(response.error);
                $("#alert_error").fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
                console.log(response.error);
           }
        }
    });     
}
```

I am then running another class callback to "refresh" the data in all the elements on the page:

```
this.refresh = function() 
{
    // Refresh the ajax requests
    this.get_contact_data();
    this.get_notes();
    this.get_contact_log();
    this.get_contact_tasks();   
}
```

This class re loads the functions which run on page load to get the inial data into the tables/fields on the page. See "get_notes" below:

```
// Get notes
this.get_notes = function() 
{
    // Get all notes and populate table
    var log_uri = this.site_url + "/contact/get_notes/" + this.contact_id; 

    this.get_data(log_uri,function(data) {
        notes = $("#contact_notes ul");
        notes.empty("");
        // Populate the contact fields, assuming there is a result to play with
        if (data != false)  {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#notes-tab .count").html("(" + data.length + ")");
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                notes.append("<li class='list-group-item' modal-id='editNoteModal' data-target='" + value.ID + "'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-3'><i class='fa fa-sticky-note mr-3'></i>" + value.timestamp + "</div><div class='col-lg-7'>" + value.note + "</div><div class='col-lg-2'><a href='#' class='edit mr-3'><i class='fa fa-edit mr-1'></i>Edit</a><a href='#' class='delete'><i class='fa fa-times mr-1'></i>Remove</a></div></div></li>");
            });
            console.log('Notes loaded');
        } else {
            notes.append("<li>There are currently no notes for this contact</li>");
        }
    });
}
```

Now the problem:

For some reason this does not update consistently in real time. The data is updated fine on the server side but on the client side the update/refresh does not always update. I might add a note and get a correct update response but the refresh method seems to be receiving the old data and always be one note behind. So the next time I add a note, the one I added before then appears and so forth.

Another problem I am experiencing is the methods seem to stack on each event so if I add one note (or one of the other methods) I will see the console say "notes loaded" but on the second note it says "notes loaded" twice, then on the 3rd note added 3 times and so forth.

I am sure there must be something fatal flaw in the design of my code here but I am not experienced enough with javascript/jquery to notice what direction I am going wrong so I can fix it.

I thought that this was an issue with ajax caching and not refreshing the result so I have adjusted the ajax request as cache none and also to send no cache headers. I am running in wamp.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your refresh code will always run before your data got updated. Because ajax is asynchronous so the code behind and below ajax will always execute nearly the time your ajax running.

At the time you run your `post_data` function to call the API, the `refresh` function got run too. So it's done before your data got updated.

You should run refresh function inside ajax callback. For example:

```
this.post_data = function(obj,uri, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        url: uri,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
           if (response.success == true)
           {

                $("#alert_success .msg").html(response.message);
                $("#alert_success").fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
           }
            else 
           {
                $("#alert_error .msg").html(response.error);
                $("#alert_error").fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
                console.log(response.error);
           }
           callback();
        }
    });     
}
```

And in `modal_update`, you pass refresh function to post_data as a callback:

```
this.modal_update = function(data) 
{//
    // Declare a few variables for the data object we've received
    obj = data.obj // The form element to serialize
    uri = data.uri;
    // Get the form ID from the data-target attribute 
    id = obj.attr('data-target');
    // URL to send to 
    url = this.site_url + uri + id;     
    // The form object
    this.post_data(obj.serialize(),url, this.refresh);
    // Hide Modal
    obj.closest('.modal').modal('hide');    
}
```

You should read more about asynchronous ajax. You can use other tricky solution is setTimeout to run `this.refresh` but I do not recommend that because you not sure when the update is done.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I do that I get the error "callback is not a function" any ideas?

Comment: @user1882233 Did you pass the refresh function as a argument when you call post_data function